# Select clustered rows from a table

Tags: matlab, random, grouping, combinatorics, matlab-table

I'll try to write my problem in a list to be more understandable:

- I have a matlab table `T` of size `1000x30`.
- All the data in the last column called 'Class' in the table has certain values of integers ranging from `1` to `20`.
- So some rows will have the value `1` which means these rows are of "Class1" and some will have the value `2` and some will have the value `20` and so on.
- The number of rows having a certain class are not equal to the number
  of rows having another class, so may be there are 100 rows have class
  `1` but 10 rows have class `2` and 500 have class `3` and so on.

This is what I want to do:

- I want to get the number of rows with the class that have the smallest
  number of rows assigned to it. So let's say Class `10` has the least rows assigned to it with `count == 3` while the rest of classes have more than 3 rows assigned to them.
- I will then have a new column called `YesNo` where it will have only the values `0` or `1`.
- Then all rows of the class with the least count (e.g Class 10 in this example) will have the value `1`.
- For the rest of rows with all other classes, I want to randomly select from every other class a similar number of rows as the class with lowest number (in this example it will be `3`).
- Then for these randomly selected rows of each other class the value in the new column `YesNo` will be `1` while for the rest of the not chosen rows will be 0.
- So in this example, this will ends up with a new column with `1000` values, where 3*20 of them will have 1's (3->number of rows assigned to class with lowest count, and 20->is number of classes) and 0 for the rest.

I wonder how this can be done in MATLAB R2015b? I know that I can create a new column in the table using `T.YesNo = newArr;` where `newArr` is a `1000x1 double` having `0` and `1` values.

As a small example, if `T` is `10x3` and has only 3 classes (`1,2,3`), below is how `T` looks:

```
ID  Name    Class   
0   'a'     3
1   'b'     2
2   'a'     2
3   'b'     2
4   'a'     3
5   'a'     1
6   'a'     1
7   'b'     2
8   'b'     1
9   'a'     2
```

So as shown above, Class3 is the one with the lowest count where only 2 rows. So I want to randomly select two rows of each Class1 and Class2 and then set the values of the new column of these randomly selected rows to `1` while the rest will be `0` as shown below:

```
ID  Name    Class   YesNo
0   'a'     3       1
1   'b'     2       0
2   'a'     2       1
3   'b'     2       0
4   'a'     3       1
5   'a'     1       0
6   'a'     1       1
7   'b'     2       0
8   'b'     1       1
9   'a'     2       1
```

Comment: Which step(s) are you having a difficulty with?

Comment: @Dev-iL sorry, I've updated my question to make it more clearer. The first part I explain the structure of my table, the second part is what I want to do.

Comment: Any chance you could show an example with a small version of `T` and the expected output...? Oh, and please also mention the version of MATLAB you're using.

Comment: Yeah, I saw. You already got my +1 ;)

Comment: @Dev-iL thank you. I hope someone will be able to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code below. It should be self-explanatory. If something is unclear - please ask.

```
function q42944288
%% Definitions
MAX_CLASS = 20;
%% Setup
tmp = struct;
tmp.Data = rand(1000,1);
tmp.Class = uint8(randi(MAX_CLASS,1000,1)); % uint8 for efficiency
T = table(tmp.Data,tmp.Class,'VariableNames',{'Data','Class'});
%% Solution:
% Step 1:
[count,minVal] = min(histcounts(T.Class,'BinMethod','integers'));
% Steps 2+3:
T.YesNo = T.Class == minVal;
% Steps 4+5+6:
whichClass = bsxfun(@eq,T.Class,1:MAX_CLASS); % >=R2007a syntax
% whichClass = T.Class == 1:MAX_CLASS; % This is a logical array, >=R2016b syntax.
for indC = setdiff(1:MAX_CLASS,minVal) 
  inds = find(whichClass(:,indC));
  T.YesNo(inds(randperm(numel(inds),count))) = true; 
end
%% Test:
fprintf(1,'\nThe total number of classes is %d', numel(unique(T.Class)));
fprintf(1,'\nThe minimal count is %d',count);
fprintf(1,'\nThe total number of 1''s in T.YesNo is %d', sum(T.YesNo));
```

Comment: What if I wanted the second or third lowest class to be the one choosing the minimum number of rows selected? Where if for example I choose the third min lowest class this means that all rows of the first and second lowest classes will have 1s and so on.

Comment: @Tak I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but instead of applying `min()` on the output(s) of `histcounts`, you should `sort` and then take whichever value you need. Please don't change the question after it was answered. If you have another problem, please post a new question and provide a link here for reference.